# How to factorize polynomials to the 5th degree?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have the polynomial:
$$2x^5-x^4+10x^3-5x^2+8x-4$$
and I know that the final result is:
$$(2x-1)(x^4+5x^2+4) = (2x-1)(x^2+1)(x^2+4)$$
But how would you do it step by step? I've seen a couple of videos and blogs about it, but they mostly use examples, where their is a common factor between the expressions but in this case their are none.

Comment: Start with the rational roots theorem.

Comment: That's the thing. I haven't learned rational roots theorem...

Comment: How about graphing it and looking for points where it crosses the $x$ axis?

Comment: Also, the rational roots theorem is pretty easy and useful for these sorts of things.

Comment: This is a non calculator question but I'll check out some videos on rational roots theorem.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't expect someone to factor a 5th degree polynomial such as this without the rational roots theorem, but that's just me.

Comment: If they know about factoring by grouping, it's a pretty good example of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every now and then, you find a polynomial of higher degree that can be factored by inspection. In this case, there's a way to just "see" one step of the factorization:

$$2x^5-x^4+10x^3-5x^2+8x-4$$

Notice that the coefficients, when grouped in pairs, are all proportional: $2, -1$ are in the same ratio as $10,-5$ and also $8,-4$. That's uncommon, but it means you can "factor by grouping":

$$(2x^5-x^4)+(10x^3-5x^2)+(8x-4)$$
$$=x^4(2x-1)+5x^2(2x-1)+4(2x-1)$$
$$=(x^4+5x^2+4)(2x-1)$$

The first step is to take the gcf out of each group, and then, since the remaining parts match ($(2x-1)$), that can be factored out. Now we're left with something that is quadratic in form, and can be factored further:

$$x^4+5x^2+4=(x^2+4)(x^2+1)$$

---

Now, in most cases, nice patterns like this do not occur. Then, you're left with the rational roots theorem. From the fact that our lead coefficient is $2$ and our constant term is $4$, we conclude that any linear factor will correspond to a zero of the form $\pm\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ is a factor of $4$ and $q$ is a factor of $2$. That gives us a few options: $\pm 4, \pm 2, \pm 1, \pm \frac12$. Trying a few of these, we see that plugging in $x=\frac12$ actually produces a value of $0$. That tells us that $(x-\frac12)$ is a factor, or clearing denominators, $(2x-1)$. You can now factor this linear piece out by long division, and end up just where we were after factoring by grouping.

Answer (score 3):

It's a theorem that the only possible rational zeroes are $p/q$, where $p$ is a factor of $4$ and $q$ is a factor of $2$. So the only possible rational zeroes are $\pm4$,  $\pm 2$, $\pm 1$ and $\pm1/2$. Try them and you see that $1/2$ is a zero. So $(2x-1)$ is a factor.

Now when you divide by $2x-1$ you get a quartic. But it's just $Q(x^2)$, where $Q$ is a quadratic. So factor $Q(x)$ as usual, replace $x$ by $x^2$ and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Laboring under the assumption that such a polynomial is not irreducible and *can* be factored (which is clear in this case since you already have a factorization), we would generally start by looking for rational roots.

The rational root theorem asserts that if $z = \frac{a}{b}$ is a rational root of the polynomial (in lowest terms), then $b$ must divide the leading coefficient, and $a$ must divide the constant term.  This gives us several potential rational roots:
$$ \left\{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm \frac{1}{2} \right\}. $$
By trial and error, it is possible to determine that the only one of these that is, in fact, a root is $\frac{1}{2}$.  From this, we know that
$$ 2x^5 - x^4 + 10x^3 - 5x^2 + 8x - 4 = \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) q(x), $$
where $q$ is a polynomial of degree 4.  Via polynomial long division, Horner's algorithm / synthetic division, or some other technique, we can deduce that $q(x) = 2x^4 + 10x^2 + 8$, thus
$$ 2x^5 - x^4 + 10x^3 - 5x^2 + 8x - 4 = \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)\left( 2x^4 + 10x^2 + 8 \right). $$
The last term is quadratic in $x^2$.  Via the quadratic formula, completing the square, or some other technique, we can determine that it, too, factors.  For example, we can "factor by grouping:"
$$ 2x^4 + 10x^2 + 8
= 2x^4 + 8x^2 + 2x^2 + 8
= 2x^2(x^2 + 4) + 2(x^2+4)
= (2x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 4).
$$
Note that both of these factors are irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ (they have complex roots, but no purely real roots), hence we can stop here.  Putting all of the pieces back together, we get
$$ 2x^5 - x^4 + 10x^3 - 5x^2 + 8x - 4
= \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) (2x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 4),
$$
which is equivalent to the factorization you gave.

Answer (score -2):

The question slightly wrong in my opinion. Please try multiplying the factors or the eqn. and lets see if you will get back the original question.

The correct equation is $P(x): 2x^5-x^4-10x^3+5x^2+8x-4$

Group and Factorize: $(2x^5-x^4) (-10x^3+5x^2) (8x-4) =0$

```
                 $x^4(2x-1)   -5x^2(2x-1)  4(2x-1)$

        Factor out $(2x-1)$ then we have $x^4-5x^2+4$
```

Our first factor of the equation is $(2x-1)$

This looks like a quadratic form but our first coefficient has 4th degree

look let's expand $x^4-5x^2+4$ and we have $(x^2-4)$ and $(x^2-1)$. $-4$ and $-1$ when added will be $-4-1 = -5$ and when multiply $-4x-1 = 4. x^2 x x^2 = x^4$
so its just splitting them and distributing them on $-4$ and $-1$ which are the product of the constant and sum of the middle term.

Now with $(x^2-4)$ and $(x^2-1)$ we can have $(x-2) (x+2)$ and $(x-1) (x+1)$.

so our final factors of the polynomial are $(2x-1) (x-2) (x+2) (x-1) (x+1)$

Therefore; the zeros of the polynomial are $1/2, 2, -2, 1, -1$.